# margin: 0 auto; in IE9 with struts 1

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have my margin: 0 auto looking good in Chrome but it's not working in IE9.  In IE9 the entire site is static against left of the screen.  I added a simple reset css statement based on some suggestions but they are not helping.

In main.css:

```
html, body {
      padding:0; 
      margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;        
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1009px;
    background-color:white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#002663;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

Updated: What the css looks like in IE's dev tools panel:

[image]

Can anyone see where I can make an improvement for IE?  Thanks.

Update: *actual* html as requested:

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<head>
    <title>Search Page</title>
    <!-- Hostname: VDDP03A-FAEF32A -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSA/styles/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSA/styles/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CSA/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CSA/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CSA/scripts/jquery.validate.js" ></script>

</head>
<body >
<div class="wrapper">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0;">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="/CSA/images/logo.jpg" width="300" align="top-left" border="0" style="margin:0;" alt="myLogo">
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
    <br />
    <h2 style="font-weight:normal;align:right;color:#002663;margin:0;">Title</h2>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr color="#002663" style="margin:0;">


<form name="form1" method="post" action="/CSA/web/CSA.do" style="margin:0;">
    <input type="hidden" name="searchType" value="myValue">
    <table width="1000px" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0;">
        <col width="285px" />
        <col width="300px" />
        <col width="278px" />
        <col width="137px" />

        <tr style="margin:0;">
            <td colspan="4">
                <h4 style="color:#002663;margin-bottom:10;margin-top:3;">Search 1:</h4>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin:0;">
            <td style=" padding-left:100px; padding-bottom:0px; width:185px;" >
            options :
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="OP1" style="border:none;">
            OP1
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="OP2" style="border:none;">
            OP2 

            </td>
            <td>
                Search Criteria&nbsp;:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="criteria" maxlength="20" size="20" tabindex="1" value="" id="searchField1">
            </td>
            <td style="min-width: 268px;">
                Date&nbsp;:&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="lossDate" maxlength="10" size="11" value="07/19/2013" id="datepicker">


            </td>
            <td style="min-width: 138px;">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" tabindex="3" value="Search" id="submit" style="margin-top:5;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <input type="reset" name="reset" tabindex="4" value="Reset" id="reset" style="margin-top:5;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<!-- Three more forms similar to the above -->

<hr color="#b0b1b2" style="margin:3;">

<table table width="1000px" border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr style="margin:0;">
            <td style="margin:0;">
                <h4 style="color:#002663" style="margin-bottom:8;margin-top:3;">Search Results:</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>



    <div styleId="errors"  style="margin:0;">

    </div>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you start with a CSS reset?

Comment: P.S. - this is 100% on the client and has nothing to do with Java or Struts.

Comment: ie9 probably has default padding or margin on the body tag, try setting the padding/margin of body to 0

Comment: Which doctype do you use? Looks much like IE's Quirks mode behavior...

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn, <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: Show us the actual HTML please, not the Struts Template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The Doctype has to be *the first thing in the document*. It goes *before* the `<html>` start tag.

Putting it where you have it is both invalid and triggering of quirks mode (and in quirks mode, all sorts of things break).

Comment: Wow, that was simple.  Thanks @Quentin.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Look up reset css when you get a chance http://www.cssreset.com/

Update:

I would suggest you take the width off of the body tag and put it in a div.

http://jsfiddle.net/KMDuw/2/

My fiddle shows a fixed width div using auto margin. If you take off the body css, you will see some space.

Can you also post your html please

Comment: unfortunately that did not work.  I am not sure I'm doing it right.  Please see my edit.

Comment: I've tried making changes based on your suggestions.  Still looks good in all browsers but IE.

Comment: Probably the table I am testing now, it looks good to me. I noticed you have padding on your wrapper so that will create a little spacing between the wrapper and the table. You should be able to tell what's causing the space with the IE dev tool. Take a screen shot if you have to. It shouldn't be hard to figure out. Make sure the screen shot captures the entire IE browser

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin:0 auto` on your body tag

```
body {
    /* background-position: 5px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    background-color: gray;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 1010px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* <--*/
}
```